# JSON text did not start with array or object

Tags: ios, json, swift, parse-server, parse-cloud-code

Working with an iOS app managing data on a Parse-Server (/Heroku).
I have the following issue when trying to save data.

Here is the code for the function where the problem happens:

```
func saveDataBlockOnline(_ dico: [String:String]) {
    let psvClassName = "Goodies",
    dataUnit=PFObject(className: psvClassName,
                      dictionary: dico)
    dataUnit.saveInBackground {
        (succeeded:Bool, error:Error?) in
        if succeeded {
            // Do something useful.
        } else {print("\(#function) Error:\(error ?? "" as! Error)")}
    }
}
```

Here is  the error I get:

```
saveDataBlockOnline Error:Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}
```

I guess I am getting some JSON answer that I don't use properly. So how should I modify the code?

There are other posts on the subject, but nothing that I found with a real solution.

A few more details may be useful:

The data saving on the server itself was working. But things started to go wrong when I added some cloud code, namely a Parse.Cloud.beforeSave to have a better control on how things are happening.

Comment: provide the code of `saveInBackground`

Comment: saveInBackground is not my code. It is part of parse. And it is working if I do not use cloud code, so saveInBackground is not the issue.

Comment: Show us an example of dico. From just the code you've shown it's the only culprit.

Comment: Here is one example:
dico = ["sentence": "1969/07/20", "orderKey": "151980480109587", "explanation": "Neil Armstrong USA."]

Answer (score 0):

The data you want to parse in not in correct format according to error message. Check your dictionary and Object(dataUnit) format

Comment: You mean the dico variable? dataUnit is only produced by PFObject.

Comment: yeah dico variable

Comment: Here is one example:
dico = ["sentence": "1969/07/20", "orderKey": "151980480109587", "explanation": "Neil Armstrong USA."]

Comment: Can you please share the debug console (po dico) for this method

Comment: What is "po dico" ?
I did : print("dico = \(dico)") when entering the function to get the result posted in my previous command.